# let only users view and use the site

Tags: javascript, logging

I have a javascript/php app and i want to do something that let only users view my app. I am thinking of webpage like gate and user should insert username & password then log in and use the app. but i have no idea how to do it. or if there is a better idea.

Comment: oh man, you must google the "php authentication"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [tons of tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+login+system) out there on how to do this, [here's one login system](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/10/cool-login-system-php-jquery/) with a bit of pizazz.